# Java project- same-package-in-different-lib problems

Tags: java

I have used both **activiti and tuscany sca** tools to make a java project by eclipse IDE, then I got a big problem.

Activiti uses **xmlschema-core.jar** and **Tuscany sca use xmlschema.jar**. However those two libs using same package (and all classes in package) **org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema**. 
When I build project, I only use methods just of the first libs, but I need all libs actived.

Would you guys give me some solutions? - Change the name of that package this the last solution I thought about :( , because those tools I mentioned before run a whole way, using that package everywhere.

Comment: And is this an issue ? Do you get conflicts ? And do you use Maven ?

Comment: changing the package name will result in unpredictable behavior of the libraries. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If both jar have same packages I guess they are different versions of the same lib, so you can try to keep only the updated one in the classpath, removing the other one.